# Ember component cannot use access controller property via "needs"

Tags: ember.js, ember-controllers

I'm trying to change a controller's property from a component as follows(JSBIN example http://jsbin.com/gevuhu):

```
App.CategoryManagerController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  selectedCategory: null,
});

App.BlogPostComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    needs: ['categoryManager'],
    selectedCategory: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.categoryManager.selectedCategory'),
    actions:{
        selectedCategory: function (){
            this.set('selectedCategory',1);
        }
    }
});
```

but getting the error `Property set failed: object in path "controllers.categoryManager" could not be found or was destroyed.`

Is it that we cannot use "needs" in components ?

Comment: there is no `needs` property for components, only controllers.  you need to pass in any data you want in the component from the component's handlebars helper

Comment: what is I want to update a property from a component in another controller ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ember Components are completely isolated from surrounding context including controllers (see [here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html)). That's the bad news. The good news is that if you pass `selectedCategory` into the component, it will become 2-way bound, so any change to it in the component will be known by your controller.

So, your controller could be something like:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ['categoryManager'],
    selectedCategory: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.categoryManager.selectedCategory'), 
    selectedCategoryChanged: function(){
      alert("NEW CATEGORY: " + this.get('selectedCategory'));
    }.observes('selectedCategory')
});
```

and then in your `application` template, you can say

```
{{ blog-post selectedCategory=selectedCategory }}
```

See a working example [here](http://jsbin.com/wabox/1/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 0):

In later version like 2.2. We'll be writing this as:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    categoryManager: Ember.inject.controller("categoryManager")
});
```

and now, categoryManager will now have the controller named categoryManager.